# signature output operator overload

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

do you know, how to write signature of a function or method for operator<< for template class in C++? I want something like:

```
template <class A> class MyClass{
  public:
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, MyClass<A> mc);
}
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, MyClass<A> mc){
  // some code
  return os;
}
```

But this just won't compile. Do anyone know, how to write it correctly?

Comment: Could you post the complete code and the error?

Comment: `MyClass.cpp:8:68: warning: friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MyClass<A>&)’ declares a non-template function`
this is complete code without #include..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All the below said, if you don't need an operator to be a friend, then don't make it a friend. For output operators in particular, in my opinion you should not make them friends. That is because if your class can be output to a stream, it should have equivalent `get` functions that provide the same data programmatically. And in that event, you can write a `operator<<` as a non-friend in terms of those `get` functions.

In case you have some good reason for making them friends, you can do a *friend definition*

```
template <class A> class MyClass {
  public:
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, MyClass<A> const& mc) {
      // ...
    }
};
```

That way you don't need the `template<...>` clause that gets you the type `A`. It's alreay known if you define the operator inside the template. Note that even though you defined it inside the template, it's not a member function. It's still a non-member, but has access to the names declared in the class (like the template parameter). For each instance of `MyClass` you create, a different *non-template* operator function is created out of that friend function that prints things.

If you want to define the template outside, you have to predeclare it to be able to declare a given specialization of it as a friend.

```
// predeclare it so you can make it a friend.
template <class A> class MyClass;
template <class A> ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, MyClass<A> const&);

template <class A> class MyClass{
  public:
    /* the "<A>" is needed - it says that a given instantiation of
       that template is a friend, and not a non-template function. */
    friend ostream & operator<< <A>(ostream & os, MyClass<A> const& mc);
};

template <class A> 
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, MyClass<A> const& mc){
  // some code
  return os;
}
```

That makes `operator<< <Foo>` a friend of `MyClass<Foo>`. If you were to omit the `<A>` or an also possible empty `<>`, the compiler would understand that as saying you made a *non-template* operator having concrete instead of templated parameters as friend.

The more easy but less "correct" solution is to make `MyClass <Foo>` have as friend all the `operator <<` instantiations. So theoretically `operator << <Bar>` could access private members of `MyClass <Foo>`. It's not what is wanted, but it works too, gaining more access than needed. It gets rid of the need for forward declaring:

```
template <class A> class MyClass{
  public:
    /* make all instantiations friends. */
    template<typename T>
    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, MyClass<T> const& mc);
};

template <class T> 
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, MyClass<T> const& mc){
  // some code
  return os;
}
```

Comment: and could you please add, how does look like the signature of non-friend operator<< overload function? thank in advance...